# How to display HTML content value in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to display my editor value from MySQL database. when I am displaying data with angularJS then it is showing text with html tag.

HTML Code:-

```
<pre>
  {{x.description}}
</pre>
```

Here I am getting output:-

```
<p>Hello India</p><br/>
<p>List Of State</p><br/>
<ol><br/>
<li>Karnataka</li><br/>
<li>Bihar</li><br/>
<li>Delhi</li><br/>
</ol>
```

But I want to result Like this:-

```
Hello India 
List of State
  1. Karnataka
  2. Bihar
  3. Delhi
```

Comment: @vivek_23 not working

Comment: My bad. I thought you were using angular CLI.

Comment: @vivek_23 I am using angularJS 1.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by using `ng-bind-html`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = `<p>Hello India</p><br/>
<p>List Of State</p><br/>
<ol><br/>
<li>Karnataka</li><br/>
<li>Bihar</li><br/>
<li>Delhi</li><br/>
</ol>`;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>


<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<pre>
 <div ng-bind-html="myText"></div>
</pre>
</div>
```